# How to make a responsive video with a width of 100% with no scroll?

Tags: css

The point is to have this video to always be 100% of the viewport width; 
But to have the height just to a point where no scroll is needed.

Can this be achieved without using overflow:hidden; ?

*You can copy paste the following as is.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Hello User!</title>   
   <style type="text/css">    
        div#video-border { border: 2px solid red; }
        video { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: 100%; }
   </style>
</head>  

<body>
   <div>
   <div>
     Im the navigation!! Wupii
    </div>
     <div>
       <p>I'm more text, more things</p>
       <p>I'm more text, more things</p>
     </div>  
     <div id="video-border">
       <video controls="controls">
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm" />
       alt text
       </video>
     </div>
     <div id="footer"><p>I'm the footer hello</p><p>I'm the footer yeah again</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure if this solution will properly work. Not sure if the video will behave on those circumstances, still... wondering.

Please advice.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a fixed height?

Comment: @PatrickJC: the user should see the video "at once" with no need to scroll.

Comment: I guess I don't follow, the code you posted with height:auto should have the video portion expand to include the entire video player, with no scroll bars... no need to define a height for this element to avoid it from giving scroll bars. I even tested what you have, and it works fine on my end, no scroll bars.

Comment: @PatrickJC You can see the scroll here: http://jsbin.com/agiyer/1/edit - I believe this scroll could not be avoided, for logical reasons. So, I have fixed the aspect ratio of the video that was wrong and messing up with the all thing. My bad. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Patrick.

If you instead want to use it in a fixed, *pre-calculated* height box, use this:

```
div#video-border {
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

video {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 150px; /* your desired height */
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The issue was video ratio related. The above code works as expected. Obviously it will have scroll bars if we but a lot of content on top and bottom of that video.